# Cross product of two Strings

Tags: scala

I am just starting out in Scala and for my first project, I am writing a Sudoku solver. I came across a great site explaining Sudoku and how to go about writing a solver: http://norvig.com/sudoku.html and from this site I am trying to create the corresponding Scala code.

The squares of a Sudoku grid are basically the cross product of the row name and the column name, this can be generated really easily in Python using a list comprehension:

```
# cross("AB", "12") = ["A1", "A2", "B1", "B2"]
def cross(A, B):
    "Cross product of elements in A and elements in B."
    return [a+b for a in A for b in B]
```

It took me awhile to think about how to do this elegantly in Scala, and this is what I came up with:

```
// cross("AB", "12") => List[String]("A1", "A2", "B1", "B2")
def cross(r: String, c: String) = {
   for(i <- r; j <- c) yield i + "" + j
}.toList
```

I was just curious if there is a better way to doing this in Scala? It would seem much cleaner if I could do `yield i + j` but that results in an `Int` for some reason. Any comments or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: `yield i + j` results in an I because `i` and `j` are type Char.

Comment: @Larsenal I assumed that is what was happening, I just thought that maybe the semantics for `Char` + `Char` would be concatenating them into a string. That was probably too hopeful though, since `Char` is essentially `Int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, addition for `Char` is defined by adding their integer equivalents. I think your code is fine. You could also use string interpolation, and spare the `toList` (you will get an immutable indexed sequence instead which is just fine):

```
def cross(r: String, c: String) = for(i <- r; j <- c) yield s"$i$j"
```

---

**EDIT**

An `IndexedSeq` is at least as powerful as `List`. Just check your successive usage of the result. Does it require a `List`? E.g. do you want to use `head` and `tail` and pattern match with `::`. If not, there is no reason why you should need to enforce `List`. If you use `map` and `flatMap` on the input arguments instead of the syntactic sugar with `for`, you can use the `collection.breakOut` argument to directly map to a `List`:

```
def cross(r: String, c: String): List[String] = 
  r.flatMap(i => c.map(j => s"$i$j"))(collection.breakOut)
```

Not as pretty, but faster than an extra `toList`.

Comment: Interpolation is Scala 2.10.  Otherwise, you can do `"%s%s".format(i,j)`, for a similar approach.

Comment: Thanks, they are probably on the same level of efficiency though right? Either way you have to concatenate. The reason I have `toList` is that I am going to use this `List` of squares to compose other data structures. Would it be better to use the `IndexedSeq`?

Comment: Just to point out, in the Scala 2.10 REPL the interpolation fails inside of `map(j => s"$i$j")`, I had to use  `map(j => i + "" + j)` again.